# subtracting a range of values by matching column entries

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I made two queries(using =QUERY) to a range of data in google sheets with the results as per the image below

[image]

I would like to:

1. subtract the values of the right/smaller table from the left/bigger table according to the
   matching column entries (B,GBP)
2. add the column entry(ies) of the right/smaller table that are missing from the left/bigger table

with the desired result looking like :

[image]

Comment: Please share a link to a copy of such a sample spreadsheet, with the link's Share permission set to "Anyone with the link... Editor." Otherwise, you're asking the volunteers here to manually type in all of your information in their own sheet before even beginning to work out a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`=query({query(A2:B7);query({D2:E5},"select Col1, -1*Col2 label -1*Col2 ''")}, "select Col1,Sum(Col2) group by Col1 Label Sum(Col2) 'Sum'")`

---

[image: Snapshot3]